# How to get Unix timestamp while pinging in Android

Tags: android, linux, unix, ping, unix-timestamp

I have been able to perform rudimentary pings in android and have been able to get the result using Processes in android. My code is as follows

```
try {
    String pingCmd = "ping -s 100 -c 10 " + host;
    String pingResult = "";
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        text.setText(inputLine + "\n\n");
        pingResult += inputLine;
        text.setText(pingResult);
    }
    in.close();
}//try
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

I am running the following command `String pingCmd = "ping -s 100 -c 10 " + host;`. I want to get the unix timestamp with each ping I have already tried the following and have not got any results with them:

`String pingCmd = "ping -s 100 -c 10 " + host+ " -D";`

`String pingCmd = "ping -s 100 -c 10 " + host+ "| while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done";`

`String pingCmd = "ping -s 100 -c 10 " + host+ "| perl -nle 'print scalar(localtime), " ", $_'";`

`String pingCmd = "ping -s 100 -c 10 " + host+ "| xargs -L 1 -I '{}' date '+%+: {}'";`

I don't get any error when I run these just no result in the textview. Please tell me how to get the unix timestamp with every ping

I expect my output to look something like this on each ping

```
[1461167279.090372] 108 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=335 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the error output stream (`p.getErrorStream()`), I think that ping under android doesn't handle all that switches, and prints error on that stream.

Comment: Tried it, doesnt give me any error o/p when things go wrong, I placed it in both the try and catch blocks hoping for some result but didnt get any. " -D" apparently works on a linux machine but not from android. What do u think I should do?